# Material design Outline textfield with white background

Tags: ios, swift, material-components-ios

Im trying to use material components library and make a textfield with outline and background color, but this is what I get

[image]

The white is outside the bounds. 
Can you help me?

this is my code

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "user")
    txtfieldEmail.placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
    txtfieldEmail.leftView = imageView
    txtfieldEmail.leftViewMode = .always

    //txtfieldEmail.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    //txtfieldEmail.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //txtfieldEmail.clipsToBounds = true

    txtfieldEmail.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    usernameTextFieldController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: txtfieldEmail)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I kept editing the form and adding more content, I ended up finding that we should be defining the style in the MDCTextInputControllerOutlined

So all I had to do was usernameTextFieldController?.borderFillColor = UIColor.white